# Unable to access virtual machine via internet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created classic Virtual Machine on Azure.Machine has created and deployed successfully and i got URL (abc.cloudapp.net). I am trying to access from internet but could not connected.I am able to login via remotely.

Comment: You need an open port (via endpoint or network security group - please see my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/a/737796/99269) on ServerFault (where this type of question belongs).

Comment: I have tried this solution but it's  not working. I am able to access the server via https://localhost:2464 inside the virtual machine but it's not working from out side. Azure is providing  a cloud app "abc.cloudapp.net:2464" but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to make sure you have a Web server such as IIS running there on the VM. Then make sure the firewall in the OS allows traffic to port 80.

If you have a classic VM, you have to add a rule in the endpoint's ACL.

If you have a Resource Manager VM, add an exception to Network Security Group's inbound security rules.

You can find the Network Security Group by finding the Network Interface Card attached to your VM. By default it is attached there.

Comment: Basically, I am running Apche tomcate on 2464 port with https(ssl) and I have already stop firewall.

Comment: I am able to access this server inside the virtual machine via remote login. I donot see any network security group....

Comment: See my edit, didn't realise it was a classic VM, you have to add an endpoint to the VM and add a rule to its ACL.

Answer (score 1):

As Juunas says, we should add the endpoint with Azure portal.
1.sign in to **the Azure classic portal**.
2.Click **Virtual Machines**, and then click the name of the virtual machine that you want to configure.
3.Click **Endpoints**. The Endpoints page lists all the current endpoints for the virtual machine. (This       example is a Windows VM. A Linux VM will by default show an endpoint for SSH.)
[image]
4.In the taskbar, click **Add**.
5.On the Add an endpoint to a virtual machine page, choose the type of endpoint. And type the port number for the incoming traffic form the internet, in private Port, type the port number on which the virtual machine is listening.

More information about add an endpoint, please refer to the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.
Best Regards,

Comment: I have tried above solution but still not working. When create an instance IP that working.

Comment: But i don't want to access via Instance IP because it will change when i restart to machine.